# Page not found in sub pages of admin panel in live server

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have hosted a website of `codeigniter` framework by using `godaddy` server.

The website is working nicely. And home page of admin panel is also working, but after first, the sub pages are giving page not found error, when I am trying to log in.

I think its a `url` directions error.

From Comment

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
Options -Indexes 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.* 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.* 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L] 
</IfModule> 

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c> ErrorDocument 404 /index.php </IfModule>
```

Comment: You need to set `base_path` in `config.php` and also `RewriteBase` in `.htaccess`

Comment: Have you set the rewritebase in .htaccess ?

Comment: applicaiton/config/config.php around line 26 `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projectname/';`

Answer (score 0):

The below settings works for me:

**First change this valiables in /application/config/config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

**Then change in .htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes 

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```